# Why doesn't my messages icon on my iPhone 5 display the number of messages?

Tags: iphone, messages

I don't know if I may have accidentally changed some settings, but now the icon on my Messages doesn't display the number of unread messages. However, my Mail app does, so I am not sure why this is. I tried going through settings to see what I could find, but to no avail.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've turned it off in Notification Center.

1. Open Settings, then scroll to Notification Center and tap it.
2. Scroll down to the "Include" section; "Messages" should be there. If not you've turned off notifications for it altogether; scroll on down to "Do Not Include" and you should see it there. In either case, tap it.
3. Tap the "Badge App Icon" switch so it's *on*.

Your messages count should be back.

Comment: I tried this fix bu it still doesn't work :(